# Returning mutiple values in the input function for `tf.py_func`

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient, backpropagation, eigenvector

I'm trying to set custom gradients using `tf.py_func` and `tf.RegisterGradient`. Specifically, I'm trying to take a gradient of an eigen value w.r.t its Laplacian. I got the basic thing working, where my `python` function returns one value, which is the eigen value. But for the gradient to work, I also need to return the eigen vector. But trying to return 2 values results in `pyfunc_1 returns 2 values, but expects to see 1 values`. How can I solve this error?

Here's the full code of my custom gradient.

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
from scipy import sparse
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops

# python function to calculate the second eigen value
def calc_second_eigval(X):
    G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(X)
    degree_dict = nx.degree(G)
    degree_list = [x[1] for x in degree_dict]
    lap_matrix = sparse.diags(degree_list, 0)-nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
    eigval, eigvec = sparse.linalg.eigsh(lap_matrix, 2, sigma=0, which='LM')
    return float(eigval[0]), eigvec[:,0]

# define custom py_func which takes also a grad op as argument:
def py_func(func, inp, Tout, stateful=True, name=None, grad=None):

    # Need to generate a unique name to avoid duplicates:
    rnd_name = 'PyFuncGrad' + str(np.random.randint(0, 1E+8))

    tf.RegisterGradient(rnd_name)(grad)  # see _MySquareGrad for grad example
    g = tf.get_default_graph()
    with g.gradient_override_map({"PyFunc": rnd_name}):
        return tf.py_func(func, inp, Tout, stateful=stateful, name=name)

# define custom second_eigval function for tensorflow
def custom_second_eigval(x, name=None):

    with ops.op_scope([x], name, "SecondEigValGrad") as name:
        eigval = py_func(calc_second_eigval,
                        [x],
                        [tf.float64],
                        name=name,
                        grad=_SecondEigValGrad)  # <-- here's the call to the gradient
        return eigval[0]

# actual gradient:
def _SecondEigValGrad(op, grad):
    # TODO: this should involve eigen vectors
    x = op.inputs[0]    
    return grad * 20 * x 

X = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([200,200],dtype=tf.float64))

second_eigval = custom_second_eigval(X)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01)
update = tf.contrib.slim.learning.create_train_op(second_eigval, optimizer,summarize_gradients=True)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    print(update.eval())
```

Comment: Why dont you return an object from the `calc_second_eigval` function like this? `return {'eigval':float(eigval[0]), 'eigvec':eigvec[:,0]}`

...or use an array `return [float(eigval[0]), eigvec[:,0]]`

Comment: Right, that's what I was doing (returning object from `alc_second_eigval` and not `py_func`. But this still results in `pyfunc_1 returns 2 values, but expects to see 1 values` error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `Tout` must be `(tf.float64,tf.float64)` instead of `[tf.float64]`

```
eigval = py_func(calc_second_eigval,
                        [x],
                        (tf.float64,tf.float64),
                        name=name,
                        grad=_SecondEigValGrad)
```

Here is an working demo

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Function in python
def dummy(x):
    return [x,x]

print(dummy([1.0,2.0]))

tf_fun = tf.py_func(dummy,[[1.0,2.0]],(tf.float32,tf.float32))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    print(sess.run(tf_fun))
```

Comment: is there a way to tell py_func the return value is going to be an array?